# I want to make a sound button that deletes itself and plays music, while making a new mute button and vice versa. Python-Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, winsound

I want to make a sound button that deletes itself and plays music, while making a new mute button and vice versa. Python-Turtle
what's wrong with my code?

```
import turtle, random, math
from turtle import*
from tkinter import*
import winsound

def playsound():
    winsound.PlaySound('mainmenu.wav',winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC)


    bsound.pack()
    bsound.place(x=600,y=400)

def stopsound():
    winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
    bsound.pack_forget()
    bsound.place_forget()

    bmute.pack()
    bmute.place(x=600,y=400)


bsound=Button(root, image=bsoundpic, command = stopsound)
bmute=Button(root, image=bmutepic, command = playsound)
```

Comment: Don't delete the button, just change the text on the button you have.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating `bsound` and `bmute` buttons and you're also attempting to pack them in the `playsound` and `stopsound` functions, but the buttons dont exist before those function are run.

Also you are using `bsoundpic` and `bmutepic` images without defining them

Lets create the buttons first and then pack them or place them in your functions.

```
import turtle, random, math
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
import winsound

root = Tk() 

bsoundpic = PhotoImage(file="soundpic.gif") 
bmutepic = PhotoImage(file="mutepic.gif") 

def playsound():
    winsound.PlaySound('mainmenu.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC)
    bmute.pack()
    bmute.place(x=600, y=400)
    bsound.pack_forget()
    bsound.place_forget()

def stopsound():
    winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
    bsound.pack()
    bsound.place(x=600, y=400)
    bmute.pack_forget()
    bmute.place_forget()

bsound = Button(root, image=bsoundpic, command = stopsound)
bmute = Button(root, image=bmutepic, command = playsound)

bsound.pack()
bsound.place(x=600, y=400)

root.mainloop()
```